# Create a new Mobile.App (Xamarin.Forms) project, try to compile, but "Failed linking references"

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2019

I have the latest visual studio 2019 (`16.2.3`) Community Edition installed with Xamarin.

When I create a brand new solution with the `Mobile App (Xamarin.Forms)` template and pick Android, I can't build it in any configuration.

It ends up with this output:

```
1>"C:\Users\myuser\source\repos\App3\App3\App3.Android\App3.Android.csproj" (Build;BuiltProjectOutputGroup;BuiltProjectOutputGroupDependencies;DebugSymbolsProjectOutputGroup;DebugSymbolsProjectOutputGroupDependencies;DocumentationProjectOutputGroup;DocumentationProjectOutputGroupDependencies;SatelliteDllsProjectOutputGroup;SatelliteDllsProjectOutputGroupDependencies;SGenFilesOutputGroup;SGenFilesOutputGroupDependencies target) (1) ->
1>(_UpdateAndroidResgen target) -> 
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1697,2): error APT0000: resource style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog (aka com.companyname.app3:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog) not found.
1>  C:\Users\myuser\source\repos\App3\App3\App3.Android\Resources\values\styles.xml(4): error APT0000: style attribute 'attr/colorAccent (aka com.companyname.app3:attr/colorAccent)' not found.
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1697,2): error APT0000: resource style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar (aka com.companyname.app3:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar) not found.
1>  C:\Users\myuser\source\repos\App3\App3\App3.Android\Resources\values\styles.xml(2): error APT0000: style attribute 'attr/windowNoTitle (aka com.companyname.app3:attr/windowNoTitle)' not found.
1>  C:\Users\myuser\source\repos\App3\App3\App3.Android\Resources\values\styles.xml(2): error APT0000: style attribute 'attr/windowActionBar (aka com.companyname.app3:attr/windowActionBar)' not found.
1>  C:\Users\myuser\source\repos\App3\App3\App3.Android\Resources\values\styles.xml(2): error APT0000: style attribute 'attr/colorPrimary (aka com.companyname.app3:attr/colorPrimary)' not found.
1>  C:\Users\myuser\source\repos\App3\App3\App3.Android\Resources\values\styles.xml(2): error APT0000: style attribute 'attr/colorPrimaryDark (aka com.companyname.app3:attr/colorPrimaryDark)' not found.
1>  C:\Users\myuser\source\repos\App3\App3\App3.Android\Resources\values\styles.xml(3): error APT0000: style attribute 'attr/colorAccent (aka com.companyname.app3:attr/colorAccent)' not found.
1>  C:\Users\myuser\source\repos\App3\App3\App3.Android\Resources\values\styles.xml(4): error APT0000: style attribute 'attr/windowActionModeOverlay (aka com.companyname.app3:attr/windowActionModeOverlay)' not found.
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1697,2): error APT0000: failed linking references.
```

Referenced packages in App3.Android.csproj are as follow:

```xml
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="4.1.0.555618" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.Design" Version="28.0.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat" Version="28.0.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.v4" Version="28.0.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView" Version="28.0.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter" Version="28.0.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils" Version="28.0.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs" Version="28.0.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Essentials" Version="1.1.0" />
```

Minimum Android version is `Android 5.0 (API Level 21 - Lollipop)`

Target Android version is `Android 9.0 (API Level 28 - Pie)`

Answer (score 16):

For whatever reason it can lock itself in this state.

Deleting `*\bin` & `*\obj` solves the issue.

Comment: can you file an issue on Github with your diagnostic build log? https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/troubleshooting/troubleshooting#diagnostic-msbuild-output

Comment: Add to this answer, sometime it failed when you copy to other computer. or try to build from folder placed in system root drive, system folders or desktop.

1. try to change location of your source 
2. check folder right (optional)

then perform @Jeremy-d step.

that how it work for me.

Comment: If just deleting doesn't work, run SDK with Admin privileges. In my case was Visual Studio...

Answer (score 5):

Do this in order:

1. Delete the **bin** & **obj** folders.
2. Rebuild the solution

Answer (score 1):

If deleting the `bin` and `obj` folders doesn't solve this for you, there is one more thing you can do.

1. You may have to run `dotnet restore` in the project folder. Easiest way to do that is by selecting Tools -> Command Line -> Developer Command Prompt from the VS menu.
2. Reinstall all NuGet packages. Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Console, then type `Update-Package -Reinstall` and hit enter

Answer (score 0):

I use Prism to create projects, and occasionally this problem occurs。

I solved it with the following：

nuget add the **Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat** to Anroid project.

clean solution and rebuild

Comment: This fixed missing AppCompat error/issue for my project. Thank you